# How to set Context menu to onBackPressedButton?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set *Context menu* to *onBackPressedButton* like "Are you sure to quit?"
Here I override `onBackPressed`: 
I don't know how to call menu. What should I register here?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    registerForContextMenu();
    return;
}
```

or what view should I attach?

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.openContextMenu();
    return;
}
```

Should I create `viewList` to it?
I've overridden `onCreateContextMenu`:

```
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    menu.add(0,YES,0,"Yes");
    menu.add(0,NO,0,"No");
}
```

I've also overridden and `onContextItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case YES:
            finish();
            break;
        case NO:
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

How must I do it?

Comment: why are you returning? remove return and try

Comment: @PreethiRao I can't even call it

Comment: You should call startActionMode() on back press.

Comment: registerForContextMenu(); put this in your onResume method

Comment: @PreethiRao It demandes View, which I haven't. Should I create one?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu refer this

Comment: your not creating contextmenu properly i feel.. refer that and create it.. then in your onBackPressed() call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `onBackPressed()` method in your class. Find a sample code below.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Really Exit?")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            LoginActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).create().show();
}
```